# Create Menu List for iPad application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to learn how I can create menu list like the List menu viewed when you choose the ringtone for your contact on iPad on mu iPad application

it's may have save button and other buttons

Help me please

Thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIPopoverController for this purpose. Have a look at the following

- [Simple UIPopover tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)
- [UIPopover Design options](http://cvil.ly/2010/04/09/ipads-mighty-popover/)